# jupyter notebookでのエラーについて: '_xsrf' argument missing from POST

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

こんにちは。

今回はdockerで構築した仮想環境化でjupyter notebookを起動した時のエラーについて解消の仕方がわからず質問させて頂きます。

まず基本スペックは以下になります。
host OS: iOS
dokcer image: jupyter/datascience-notebook
エラー内容: '_xsrf' argument missing from POST

エラー概要は以下になります。

現在、Dockerについて学習しており、その学習過程で実践的な環境を構築しようと考え、DockerのコンテナでPythonの練習環境を構築しようとしています。
上記Dockerイメージのもと、「$docker run -d --name notebook -p 8888:8888 -v (ディレクトリの指定) jupyter/datascience-notebook」でコンテナを作成・起動した際は大抵、pythonファイルも問題なく起動し、プログラムを通常通り動作するのですが、これを再起動した場合やコンテナを削除して作り直した場合などに、pythonファイルを新規作成しようとすると、上記のようなエラーが出ます。
英文サイトなどを見てみてもどうも合点がいかず、ここで質問させて頂きました。
どういった場合にこのエラーが出るのかも正直わかっていないのが現状です。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: それっぽいIssueが立ってますね https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3506

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jupyter notebook`にアクセスできれば、任意のコードが実行できるので、トークンベース認証によるアクセス制限がかかっています。通常は`Jupyter notebook`の起動時にトークンが自動的にブラウザーに送られて問題なく起動します。今回のエラーは、何らかの理由でトークンの処理に問題が発生したものと思われます。

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html

当面の対応については、メッセージの中にトークンが表示されているので、それを使ってログインします。以下は成功した場合のメッセージですが、エラーの場合もエラーメッセージの上にトークンが表示されていると思います。

```
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time, 
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=13e1a5af13049b157535e1ac6054679369777254b4feecc5
[I 09:12:00.292 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from 127.0.0.1
```

また、パスワードを使うことも可能です。
設定ファイルがなければ以下のコマンドで作成して、

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

次のコマンドでパスワードを設定できます。

```
$ jupyter notebook password
Enter password:  ****
Verify password: ****
[NotebookPasswordApp] Wrote hashed password to /Users/you/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
```

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html